# How to put a if condition so that it matches these two conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two variables sellprice and buyprice , i need to check these two conditions before procedding it further .

1. Difference between  buyprice - sellprice  should not be less than 1 .
2. Difference between sellprice - buyprice  should not be greater  than 6 .

I could be able to achive the first one , but not both at the same time

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function verify()
{



var sellprice = parseFloat(150);
var buyprice = parseFloat(148);

if(buyprice -sellprice>=-1.00)
{

alert('ok');
}

else
{
alert('false');
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>



<button type="button" onclick="verify()">Verify</button>

</body>
</html>
```

require your advice , if nything better can be done to achieve this .

Comment: `buyprice -sellprice>=-1.00 && buyprice -sellprice <= 6.00`

Comment: Any idea why this is downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as many conditions you like with AND (`&&`) and OR (`||`)

```
function verify() {

    var sellprice = parseFloat(150);
    var buyprice  = parseFloat(148);

    var total = buyprice - sellprice;

    if (total >= 1 && total <= 6) {
        alert('ok');
    } else {
       alert('false');
    }

}
```

If you read it out, it makes sense, `total` is more or equal to 1, AND less or equal to 6

Answer (score 1):

You can check the two conditions at once using `&&`:

```
if(buyprice-sellprice>=-1.00 && buyprice-sellprice <= 6.00)
{

    alert('ok');
}

else
{
    alert('false');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj6he/3/)

```
var sellprice = parseFloat(150);
var buyprice = parseFloat(148);

var sum=buyprice -sellprice;
if(sum>=1 && sum<=6)
{

alert('ok');
}else{
alert('no');
}
```

OR use conditional operator

```
var isRight=(sum>=1 && sum<=6)?alert("yes"):alert("no");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
if(buyprice - sellprice >= -1 && sellprice - buyprice <= 6) {
   alert('ok');
}
else {
    alert('false');
}
```

Try to check these conditions one by one, it is a good habit - when one of conditions fail you don't have to check the others, so it is faster. Always try to avoid && and | |.

```
var isOk = false;
if(buyprice - sellprice >= -1 ) {
   if(sellprice - buyprice <= 6) {
       isOk = true;
   }
}
alert(isOk);
```